# How to add a line break inside metatag description

Tags: facebook, tags, meta

I'm trying to add a line break inside my meta tag description.

`<meta property="og:description" content="Say goodbye to dirty dishes. Spray on and come back later"/>`

I'm mainly doing this for my facebook share dialog window. I would like the second sentence ("Spray on and come back later") to appear on it's separate line below the first sentence.

I've done numerous searches but can't seem to find the answer.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: it's really not possible at all? Any hacks or work arounds?